# Get a list of all schemas for a publication, including inherited ones via core service

Tags: schema, core-service

I wish to retrieve a list of all schemas for a given publication - including inherited ones.

Originally I was using the `getSearchResults` core service method with a filter constraining to the current publication and a search type of `ItemType.SCHEMA`. However, this only returns schemas that are defined in the supplied publication - ignoring any inherited schemas. Removing the publication filter means I end up with all schemas in any publication.

So instead, I've started looking at the `getList` core service method, passing in a `BluePrintChainFilterData` filter with the direction set to `BluePrintChainDirection.UP`. However, this isn't returning what is expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: Turns out my original technique would also have worked. However it's good to know there are alternative ways of achieving the same result. I'm now wondering which is the more efficient? getList or getSearchResults? Thanks, Ben

Comment: GetList uses a DB Stored Procedure + a few abstraction layers and is an internal call, GetSearchResults uses the SOLR search engine, and relies on it being accurate. I would use the GetList method simply because it _must_ work always, while the Search may not give you the correct results if the search index is not maintained properly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use `RepositoryItemsFilterData`:

```
var filter = new RepositoryItemsFilterData();
filter.ItemTypes = new[] {ItemType.Schema, };
filter.Recursive = true;
var schemasXml = ClientAdmin.GetListXml("tcm:0-2-1", filter);
```

You can also use `OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData` in the similar way, but on the BuildingBlocks level