# How to disable a default RTF button in all schemas in SDL Tridion enabling it only in a single field?

Tags: 2013, rtf

By default tridion enables a new RTF button in all RTF fields under Edit Formatting Features. I need to disable my newly added RTF button in all fields and should enable it only in one RTF field. Is there a way to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Related? http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/7669/how-to-deselect-an-allowed-action-via-core-service-for-a-rtf-field

Answer (score 1):

Open them one by one and make the required changes.

Comment: Am looking for an automated process as i have 113 schemas which atleast has 3 RTF fields each.

Answer (score 1):

As Frank's comment suggests, if you want an automated process to update multiple schemas at once you are going to want to use the Core Service. His link shows a similar scenario.

In your case you could simply retrieve a list of all schemas as discussed [here](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/444/get-a-list-of-all-schemas-for-a-publication-including-inherited-ones-via-core-s), then follow my solution in Frank's link to retrieve the SchemaData XSD for each schema. Once you have this, some string/XML manipulation would let you add the "DisallowedActions" element needed to turn off your feature.