# How to deselect an allowed action via core service for a RTF field

Tags: 2013, core-service, rtf

I am unable to get the allowed actions for a RTF field. any suggestions to allow or deny actions would be of great help.

```
OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData filter = new OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData();
foreach (XElement element in client.GetListXml(itemId, filter).Nodes())
{                    
    SchemaFieldsData schemaFieldsData = client.ReadSchemaFields(element.Attribute("ID").Value, false, null);
    for (int i=0; i<schemaFieldsData.Fields.Length;i++)
    {
        ItemFieldDefinitionData firstField = schemaFieldsData.Fields[i];                                              
        if (firstField.GetType().Name.Equals("XhtmlFieldDefinitionData"))
        {
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is managed in the SchemaData of the schema your item uses, rather than the ItemFieldDefinitionData. If you don't know the schema ID your item will use you can use something like

`var schemaId = element.Attribute("SchemaId");`

to retrieve it. Once you have this Schema ID,

```
var schemaData = (SchemaData)client.ClientInstance.Read(schemaId, null);
```

will return the SchemaData for the item you have found.

The property schemaData.xsd allows you to get and set the source XML for the schema itself.

In your case you'd be looking to update the "DisallowedActions" element contained within the node corresponding to your "XhtmlFieldDefinitionData" field.